# How to send a text from one android client to another through server?

Tags: android, .net, sockets

Situation:

Let's say i have 2 emulators and I want to send a text from one emulator to another. What is the way to solve this? Can i using .Net web service?

Answer (score 0):

Anythings that can forward your messages from Android client.
So if you don't want to make it to complex, consider to use some kind of RESTful WS for example.
Good luck

For .NET platform, maybe you want to make a quick look on this link  [link to some blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/04/03/creating-restful-services-using-wcf.aspx)